# Android APK file too big because of lib directory

Tags: android, apk

I'm building an Android application which size was around 4MB APK file. From a couple of weeks ago, when building signed app, generated APK file is around 17MB.

After investigating why is this happening, I've discovered that new APK archives contain `/lib` directory which didn't exist on old APKs that were 4MB in size. Does anyone know why this lib directory suddenly appears in APK archive and is there a way to remove it?

Structure of `/lib` directory inside APK archive is:

```
/lib
    /arm64-v8a
    /armeabi
    /armeabi-v7a
    /mips
    /x86
    /x86_64
```

I have recently updated Android Studio to 2.0 and also upgraded gradle. Can this be an issue and is there some configuration parameters that can solve this problem?

My gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir { dirs 'aars' }
}

android {
    // when changing this, YOU MUST change C:\AndroidADT\sdk\build-tools\xx.yy.zz\dx.bat to have -> set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    def homeDir = System.getenv('HOMEDRIVE') + System.getenv('HOMEPATH');

    signingConfigs {
        cinema {
            storeFile = file("keystore\\cinema.keystore.jks")
            storePassword = "cinema"
            keyAlias = "cinema"
            keyPassword = "cinema"
        }
        dev {
            storeFile = file("keystore\\development.keystore.jks")
            storePassword = "development"
            keyAlias = "development"
            keyPassword = "development"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        cinema {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.cinema
            jniDebuggable false
            applicationIdSuffix ".cinema"
        }
        dev {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
            jniDebuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'src-gen']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']

            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        debug {
        }
        dev {
            res.srcDirs = ['res_dev']
        }
        cinema {
            res.srcDirs = ['res_cinema']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.markupartist.android.widget:pulltorefresh:1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/estimote-sdk-preview.jar')

    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/FastPaySDK_pro.jar')
}
```

Comment: exclude /lib while packing

Comment: @Sibidharan I forgot to mention, I'm beginner in Android programming. How can I do that in Android Studio?

Comment: You are creating APK of in which flavour? Release or Debug or Test?

Comment: Please post your gradle file.

Comment: @MartinoLessio I've edited my question and added gradle file content.

Comment: @cakan do you need all those library in your project?

Comment: @HardikAmal Yes. They were always here and size of APK was 4MB. If I exclude some of them, size doesn't change drastically.

Comment: if yes then go for proguard. set minifyenabled to true and set some rules of proguard. Using proguard the size of apk does reduce. also check for the unused drawables and xml in res folder.

Comment: Problem is that a /lib folder is packed inside APK, which wasn't there previously. That's what makes APK file 17MB instead of 4MB as before.

Comment: @cakan did you see what those armeabi folder contains?

Comment: Each contains files named `libcardioDecider.so`, `libcardioRecognizer.so`, `libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so`, `libopencv_core.so`, `libopencv_imgproc.so`. Some directories contain only `libcardioDecider.so` file.

Comment: check this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794584/exclude-jnilibs-folder-from-production-apk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108898/discussion-between-hardik-amal-and-cakan).

Comment: Have you import project from Eclipse to Android Studio???

Comment: No, project is in Android Studio for over a year now. I think it all started happening after AS and gradle update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this to exclude SO file from the release build

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi" // includes ARM SO files only, so no x86 SO file
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Have not tested,maybe you can try out: abiFilters "" to exclude all the .SO files

Comment: Adding ndk { abiFilters= " " } in release build reduces the .apk size and it supports the latest devices. Support for "armeabi" has been removed in NDK 17.

Answer (score 8):

Problem was generated by PayPal SDK which includes card.io libraries. I have found that solution for my problem is to [disable card.io card scanning](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#disabling-cardio-card-scanning):

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'
}
```

Or to completely exclude `card.io` library:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
}
```

I hope this will help somebody.