How can I reduce my APK size? The lib folder is too big in it
I'm currently working on a small project utilizing GeckoView. Despite starting with an empty project and merely adding GeckoView to the dependencies (without adding any resources or images), the APK size has bloated to over 500 MB. Upon analyzing, it appears that the .so files in the lib folder are contributing significantly to this size. I'm unsure why this is the case and how to reduce it. Is there a specific mode or method I should use?
APK analyzation
I also tried to make an aab file
None of them worked for me. I am a beginner in this field and I don't really know how can I fix that.
My app gradle file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.pank"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pank"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)

    var geckoViewVersion = "112.0.20230406114409"
    implementation("org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview:$geckoViewVersion")
}

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2/")
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Test"
include(":app")
 


The largest library is libxul which is required because you seem to use XUL framework for developing apps. If you want smaller apps you shouldn't use such frameworks.

What if I only want to build to "armeabi-v7a" and not for the other 3?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36567235/150978

maybe you can add this
ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
}
we have similar issue, I am experimenting to add geckoview in old android devices which requires smaller libraries. but can't find a good way to reduce the libxul.so

Duplicates Android APK file too big because of lib directory
I decrease bundle size by adding
ndk {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }

into release in buildTypes in build.gradle.kts
